# npm install error: saveError: cannot install react native checkbox

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm-install

I am currently building a cellphone application with react native. To create checkbox list, I was trying to install the component through npm.

```
npm install react-native-checkbox --save
```

However, I got two errors and I had no idea how to solve them. I have tried to clean the cache or reinstall the node but they didn't solve the problem. Could some give me some suggestions? Would appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: It means there is no package.json in that location... Make sure you're in the right directory. You seem to be in your home directory.

Comment: so I should install the checkbox package in my app's directory, right?

Comment: Well yes, how do you want your app to get access to the package if you dont add it there?

Comment: You really should read up on npm if you have to ask that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means there is no `package.json` in that location... Make sure you're in the right directory. You seem to be in your home directory.

To install and save a package you need to have a package.json, which there should already be one in your **projects folder**.

After navigating to the right folder, repeat your `npm install` and everything should be fine and dandy.